# Calculating file size for recording huge combination events

Tags: windows, filesize

I'm trying to write down all possible combinations of 40 numbers from a given 80 numbers. Currently  file size is 28GB and growing. I want to terminate it if it is no where close to completion yet.
For this is there a possible way to compute file size.
Total combinations are 80!/(40!*40) which is huge itself. So each event is 40 numbers with spaces. Is there a way to compute file size required to record this?

Answer (score 2):

[Sterling's approximation for factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives a lower bound on the number of combinations as

[image: equation]

where a is 80 and b is 40 in this case.

This simplifies further, and because a is twice b it comes out as

[image: equation]

which can be evaluated as a little more than 9x10^22.

This is already a lower bound, so if each of the combinations required only a single byte to store (if you're storing them efficiently as numbers it would take about 17 bytes each, or as strings 40 bytes each), then this would still require about 100 zettabytes. To give you an idea of how much this is, Google is estimated to have a total storage capacity of about an exabyte, and a zettabyte is 1000 of those.

Comment: Using python that natively deals with multiprecision integers, we can easily compute it. The exact value is `107507208733336176461620`, not far from `1.075e23` or `10.75x10^22` with your notation

Comment: Good point. I probably should have thought about how big the number would be before I started approximating it!